# Building Alexa inventory management skill

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I would like to build an Amazon Alexa skill that can read back information on what I have in my inventory. I was thinking about creating a website, storing my inventory in a spreadsheet, and then uploading the spreadsheet to the website. Alexa would then be able be able to crawl the spreadsheet and tell me certain information based on what I ask. I already know the basics of building a skill through Amazon's develop console, but how would I incorporate Alexa going to a spreadsheet on my website? I've read about people using DynamoDB, but haven't seen anyone use a spreadsheet. Advice?

Comment: It depends on the source for your spreadsheets as an example, If you were utilizing google sheets as your source and node.js as the programming language you would start here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs there is as you would expect other languages in the guide, but this gives you a complete code breakdown of extracting cells, and rows. start here and get a functioning program to pull your data then implement it into your Alexa skill.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSoup  https://jsoup.org if you can use Java.

Jsoup helps to parse any unstructured html with easy to use methods.

I used this in my alexa skill as my backend service have not exposed an API and hence I had to crawl a web page having the results of API.

Spreadsheets when ultimately loaded in browsers becomes an HTML and JSoup is the library that helps to parse any tag, any attribute in your html.